# Как эмулировать нажатие на Enter на Java?

Tags: java

В общем, я только начинаю изучать Java и решил что уже в принципе это можно как-то использовать. Хочу попробовать написать маленькую программу, которая автоматически будет нажимать на Enter при появлении в игре кнопки принять.
Объясните новичку возможно ли вообще такое осуществить на Java и с чего начать? Базовые знания уже имеются, меня бы просто направить  Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Возможно, например при помощи [java.awt.Robot](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html), он умеет:

1. Снимать скриншоты
2. Манипулировать мышью и клавиатурой
3. ...
4. Profit!

Answer (score 8):

Можно сделать с помощью класса [Robot](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html). Например, для нажатии клавиши <kbd>Enter</kbd>:

```
Robot r = new Robot();
r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
```